# select all form elements that are selected as well as non-selectable form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have markup that looks something like this:

```
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="follower_id" name="event[task_followers_attributes][0][follower_id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-typeahead-associated-id="1" value="1" selected>Administrator</option>
    <option data-typeahead-associated-id="2" value="2">Marketing Guy</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" data-typeahead-associated-id="2" name="event[followers_attributes][1][id]" value="2">  
</form>
```

I want to find all form elements who have the data attribute "data-typeahead-associated-id". However, if the form element is a form element that is selectable (e.g. select, radio button), then I only want the data-typeahead-associated-id for the one that is selected. Since input fields do not have multiple options, I want all input fields that match the "data-typeahead-associated-id" attribute.

Therefore, in the above example I want the select option with value 1, not 2. And I also want the input field with value 2.

I thought up this solution, which appears to be working:

```
$('form').find('[data-typeahead-associated-id]').not('option:not(:selected),input[type="radio"]:not(:checked),input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)')
```

But is there a more stable, elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this solution is more efficient.
But I notice that You have used a double **not** instruction that it's an **affermative** instruction at the end.

My solution is to split into two simpler instructions.
First select all elements with `[data-typeahead-associated-id]`
Second filter items to your liking (`:selected`, `:checked`, `:input`)
In this way you have more control over the elements.

Try:

```js
var elements = $('form').find('[data-typeahead-associated-id]');
var result = elements.filter(":selected, :checked, :input");

//Following is only to display results
$.each(result, function(index, value){
$('#result').append("<p>Index: " + index + " | Element: " + value + " | Value: " + $(value).val() +"</p>");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="follower_id" name="event[task_followers_attributes][0][follower_id]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-typeahead-associated-id="1" value="1" selected>Administrator</option>
    <option data-typeahead-associated-id="2" value="2" >Marketing Guy</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" data-typeahead-associated-id="2" name="event[followers_attributes][1][id]" value="2">  
</form>

<!-- Following is only to display results -->
<div id="result">
</div>
```